# Post Upload File aborting

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, upload

i'm having a problem with a file post i hope you can help me.

Here is the problem:

I have a *.aspx page that contains a form, that form is described here:

```
<form id="formUpload" name="formUpload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.aspx" target="iframex">
```

This upload.aspx page get the file do a lot of stuff and is supposed to register a startup script with a variable (errorFlag) that i use in upload.aspx after everything is executed:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        if (errorFlag) { //*** C# gives me this variable
            self.parent.$("#iframex").show();
            self.parent.upload(false);
        }
        else {
            self.parent.upload(true);                
        }
    });
```

The problem is that i debugged every server code and everything is working fine, after there is no c# code to execute anymore (even after the unload) it just don't "come back" to render the HTML and after sometime it aborts the post.

Another problem is that it just occurs when i'm executing it on server, local works ok.

Thanks in advance, sorry if i couldn't be more clear.. is hard even to explain.

Answer (score 0):

If it works locally and not on production then the issue could be as simple as your max file size for upload.  Iis will limit the file upload to 4mb be default. You need to change this in the web.config under 
system.webserver maxAllowedContentLength and also system.web maxrequestlength.

you might find that iis is simply abandoning your upload.

Comment: Thomas, even thought this didn't worked, i collect some more info that you may use to help me. Actually i got 2 servers test-production and production, in production works fine and in test-production is not working. I tried deleting some data from my file and that actually worked in test-production, but i don't know why i can't make it work as it works local and in production with the full file, do you guess anything else? Thanks again for your help

Comment: If it works on one full IIS server and not the other then it must be a configuration issue.
Posibilites are:
1. you have not synched the web.config setting on both machines
2. you have a permission issue with where you are saving the uploaded files to. (are you saving to the hard drive?). Perhaps you haven't allowed access to the account to save to a folder and are swallowing the error.
3.  that's it really - are both test and production using the same OS/IIS versions?

you could post your upload code and web.config if you wish.